# Using trigger to update a value

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

How do I write a simple trigger to check when salary is updated it is not over 5% for an existing faculty member.

I have a block of code here.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_Not_over_5per
BEFORE UPDATE OF F_SALARY ON FACULTY
DECLARE 
sal FACULTY.F_SALARY%TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT FACULTY.F_SALARY INTO sal FROM FACULTY
-- how do I use the WHERE CLAUSE here so that I get the salary affected

-- do some math on the first and second salary
-- if less than 5%, keep update, if not, reject update.
END;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a SELECT in the trigger **(*)**. Define the trigger as FOR EACH ROW and you can have access to the old and new values of any column belonging to the table.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_Not_over_5per
BEFORE UPDATE OF F_SALARY ON FACULTY
FOR EACH ROW
```

So your code would look like:

```
if :new.f_salary < :old.f_salary * 1.05 then
     raise_application_error (
       -20000
       , 'salary increase must be at least 5%'
    );
end if;
```

This way of handling the rule violation is just a suggestion. You do whatever you need to. You don't need to handle the ELSE branch: Oracle will apply the update by default.

---

**(*)** In fact Oracle will hurl a mutating table exception if you do try to execute the query you want to write. [Find out more](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle%20mutating%20table).